# Sugarcrm date picker disable dates before current date

Tags: javascript, yui, sugarcrm

Has any one managed to disable dates on sugars date picker before the current date?

I am calling it in a custom programmed module like so:

```
<script id="script" type="text/javascript">

YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function()
{
    var now = new Date();
    Calendar.setup ({

        inputField : "date",
        ifFormat : cal_date_format,
        daFormat : "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%P",
        button : "date_start_trigger",
        singleClick : true,
        step : 1,
        weekNumbers: false,
        startWeekday: 0


    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no upgrade safe way to do this.

But have solved it by adding a parameter in include/javascript/calendar.js

Search for line calendar.cfg.setProperty("selected" just after that line add following code

```
if(typeof(params.customMinDate) != 'undefined')
   calendar.cfg.setProperty("minDate", params.customMinDate);
```

And then in your calendar setup array, you should add following param,

```
customMinDate : new Date(),
```

And that should now disable all dates in past. But this works on for the calendar pops up on text field, and not when you click on calendar image.

If you find its solution, do share here, which will help others and me too.

I hope SugarCRM will overcome this limitation and make it more flexible in future releases.